# NFC with Meteor.js

Tags: meteor, nfc

Is it possible to register NFC events with Meteor.js framework?
What would be the minimal example?
We chose Meteor.js for it's suitability with lean development, we understand that there are more efficient tools for mobile development.

Comment: I assume you're referring to cordova/phonegap deployments. In this case you're looking for a plugin for one of them that can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the Cordova plugin [com.chariotsolutions.nfc.plugin](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.chariotsolutions.nfc.plugin) which is documented as handling NFC for android and windows phone.

With the cordova plugin, it appears to be (meteor standard) simple through the user of the NFC object:
`nfc.addNdefListener(callback, [onSuccess], [onFailure]);`
NDEF events are fired when the NDEF tag is read.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: And text answers will be outdated upon an update to the relevant APIs. I see some value in your point though; all answers should probably have both.